# Top of my sourdough starter has gone grey

Tags: sourdough-starter

I started my first sourdough starter about three weeks ago and after one week put it in refrigerator and the next week fed if 3 times in 12hours intervals an then put it back into fridge , but now there is some greyness on its surface which seems part of the starter itself and is not like fungal mould but i'm worried if it's safe to use or not ?

Answer (score 5):

Gray discoloration is normal and nothing to worry about. If you see orange or pink then your starter should be thrown away.

Answer (score 3):

See this on mine too. Usually, it's just a bit dried surface. If it doesn't look moldy (and starts to have other colours), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Grey discoloration is normal (and if you see water forming):
this is also known as `hooch`, an alcoholic breakdown of the starches/carbs by the bacteria.

> Only if you see pink spots should you throw the starter away.

Answer (score 1):

Just pour the grey stuff away or scoop it off. Then it shouldn't come back unless you leave it for too long again :)